# Добавить контекст в django flatpages

Tags: django, context, mixins

Есть базовый шаблон сайта base.html в который из приложения магазина передается mptt-объект с  категориями товара, все приложения в своих шаблонах наследуют базовый шаблон и в своих view наследуются от Mixin, для получения в контекст mptt nodes. Все работает отлично, пока не потребовалось создать flatpage. Никак не могу понять как передать в контекст flatpage нужные данные

Comment: Проще для этих целей использовать [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors).

Comment: Спасибо! действительно удобно получилось. То что надо!

Comment: самый простой способ на самом деле был не использовать flatpage, вместо этого создать свою модель страницы.